# I'm registered with Google: can I set a password for standard email login?

Tags: support, login

I don't like having an account which depends on another one. I prefer to have separate accounts, but I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have them.

We use OpenId - which means you can associate your account with any OpenId provider (Google, Facebook, Yahoo and a bunch of others, even your own if you so wish).

Even our Stack Exchange email/password form is backed up by our own OpenId provider.

You can associate your account with several of these *at once*, meaning that you can login using any of them, and if one goes down, you have other options to login.

Answer (score 3):

You can [sign up for a Stack Exchange OpenId account](https://stackexchange.com/users/login#create-account) in order to have a set of credential that are separate from any existing account you have.